# Execute PHP file in background

Tags: php, multithreading

I have some php code, that execute for a very long time.

I need to realise next scheme:

1. User enter on some page(page 1)
2. This page starts execution of my large PHP script in background .(Every change is writting to database)
3. We sent every N seconds query to database to get current status of execution.

I don't want to use exec command because 1000 users makes 1000 php processes. It's not way for me...

Comment: Because this process must go without user's activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you basically want a queue (possibly stored in a database) and a command line script ran by cron that process queued items.

**Clarification**: I'm not sure about what's unclear about my answer, but this complies with the two requirements imposed by the question:

1. The script cannot be aborted by the client
2. You share a single process between 1,000 clients

Answer (score 1):

Use http requests to the local http server from within your script in combination with phps `ignore_client_abort()` function.

That way you keep the load inside the http servers worker processes, have a natural limit and queuing of requests comes for free.

Comment: I would also remind him to use `set_time_limit(0)` and `register_shutdown_function()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CLI](http://www.php-cli.com/) to execute multiple PHP scripts

or

you can try [Easy Parallel Processing in PHP](http://phplens.com/phpeverywhere/?q=node/view/254)